# Adding 10000 placemark with hover on google map taking 2 hour in C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps-api-3

I am adding 10000 place mark on google map with hover but it is taking around 2 hour .Which is not good for any user.

Please suggest me what is the idle time taken by the google map and how i can speed up.

I am doing following steps

1) select distinct locations form database for selected person.

2) Make script to add all the locations of salesman.

3) Call google map api(v3) and pass script to it to load all values.

Please suggest

Comment: Are you loading them onto your google maps via a C# plugin on the aspx code?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps wasn't made for handling that many markers at the same time and the speed will be quite horrible. Try to limit the amount of markers placed by grouping them together if there are several near each other until the user zooms in and only load the markers needed for the current visible area.

I'm not really sure how you are displaying this map but my guess is in a webbrowser control? If so, then you could use a helper library such as Marker Clusterer or Marker Manager (both available at http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) to help you out.

Comment: Actually, you're wrong. Google offloads all the locations to their server when you add them, and then as you pan the map around they send down the new placemarks. The service is really quite efficient.

Comment: Please give a source that confirms that statement. I've used Google Maps in a few scenarios and after adding about 200-300 markers I've run into huge performance problems until I started grouping them myself.

Comment: i am doing this in web browser and i need to show location of person that are very huge because they get recorded on daily basis

Comment: Um, experience and debugging in the browser. What version of Google Maps were you using?

Comment: It dawned on me while I was asleep/showering that I was loading data from a KML, not in the page via javascript via server emission.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how much this will help you with 10,000 markers, but after a little bit of searching, it looks like there are more efficient ways of managing markers than just dumping them all onto a map:

http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/

Based on the benchmarks at the end, it's still going to take a few minutes to load 10,000 markers. Google Maps certainly wasn't designed to handle that many markers at once. The best way to speed things up is to only add the necessary markers. I can't imagine anyone making any sense of 10,000 markers. Narrow it down to only a handful that an end-user can understand and work with.

Comment: Actually, you're wrong. Google offloads all the locations to their server when you add them, and then as you pan the map around they send down the new placemarks. The service is really quite efficient.

Comment: Based on the figures in the question, it's loading at about 1.5 markers/second, I wouldn't call that efficient. Regardless, 10,000 markers is going to be an indecipherable mess to anyone unless you're grouping them or filtering 99.99% of them out.

Comment: It dawned on me while I was asleep/showering that I was loading data from a KML, not in the page via javascript via server emission.